# AWS IAM Roles - Best Practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm creating a serverless app using API Gateway and Lambda. When creating roles for my API. What is best practice, How granular should I get?

Should I create a new role for every resource?
Or every method?
Or for API Gateway and Lambda respectfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its application specific, but the general rule is to follow **AWS best practice** and [grant least privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) permissions for accessing your resources.

Following the AWS best practice, you:

> **Start with a minimum set of permissions** and grant additional permissions as necessary. Doing so is more secure than starting with permissions that are too lenient and then trying to tighten them later.

More specific to your question. API Gateway don't have roles, they have [resource policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html). They are generally used to specify permissions regarding who/what can invoke your API. I would recommend checking out **official AWS examples** of such policies and model your policies based on them, which includes how detailed they are: [API Gateway resource policy examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html)

Since in your setup, lambda is going to be accessing your other resources (e.g. S3, DynamoDB) you should specify its permissions to access these resources in its [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html).

If you have several lambda functions having same permission they can reuse the same role. Also if you want to use different roles, you may create [IAM custom managed policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#customer-managed-policies) which you could attach and reuse across different roles.